# How to pass the progress from API call to waiter

Tags: r, shiny, progress-bar, httr, waiter

I would like to capture the progress of the API call and update the waiter. This does not display progress on the UI end. not sure why. If I remove the If, just have a for loop, the API calls completes and then the for loop executes,then I can see the waiter progressing from 0 to 100%. Is it because UI is holding up while while a server-side operation is running?

```r
library(shiny)
library(waiter)
library(promises)
library(future)

foo <- function() {
     # Simulte a slow download
    cap_speed <- httr::config(max_recv_speed_large = 10000)
    x <- httr::GET("http://httpbin.org/bytes/102400", httr::progress(con = stderr()), cap_speed)
 }

ui <- fluidPage(
  useWaiter(),
  useHostess(),
  waiterShowOnLoad(
    color = "#f7fff7",
    hostess_loader(
      "loader", 
      preset = "circle", 
      text_color = "black",
      class = "label-center",
      center_page = TRUE
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  hostess <- Hostess$new("loader")
  
  f <- future({ foo() })  # Create the future

  for(i in 1:10){
    if(future::resolved(f)) {
      hostess$set(100)
      waiter_hide()
      break
    } else {
      hostess$set(i * 10)
    }
  }  
}
 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think it's not possible to get the real progress. But one could use a spinner that runs until the call has finished.

Comment: I took a look... In fact it should be possible if you do the API call with JavaScript.

Comment: How do we do API call with JS, I just use R packages. Moreover, onLoad of the shiny app, the the API call holds up the  proper rending of the screen, so I have used the caller to make the API in the background so that it does not hold the loading screen. Then, came across waiter package, thought maybe I could remove the callr and just use the waiter page, and run API directly. Can you provide some example on how to execute API call using JS, I have many API calls being executed, so may be JS would be faster than R package ?

Comment: user> Is it an API call to download a file?

Comment: I have 3 API calls with different tokens that pull that data and display in shiny table, on the initial load of the APP.

Comment: user> So it is a download, with a GET request?

Comment: After that, based on the Record ID,  from one of the API calls I download csv file for each record and display it in another shiny Tab. This doesn't execute unless the tab is clicked. To avoid repeated API calls to download the same file, I store the data ( record id and csv df as list columns)  as a dataframe in an .RDS object. So, the app reads this info in memory and anti_join to download the csv file for new records. Not sure, if there is a better way to approach this

Comment: `data <- REDCapR::redcap_read_oneshot(redcap_uri = url, token = token)$data`
I use the REDCapR package like above. Its is a wrapper on GET request

Comment: user> I only know (I think) how to do for a download.

Comment: `token <- token
url <- url
formData <- list("token"=token,
                 content='file',
                 action='export',
                 record='31',
                 field='run_csv_file',
                 event='',
                 returnFormat='json'
)
response <- httr::POST(url, body = formData, encode = "form")
result <- httr::content(response)
head(result)
f <- file('/tmp/file.raw.txt', 'wb')`
This is how I download the file, I just need to make sure the User is engaged with the waiter so that, progress shows that something is working behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using the **httr** package to do the request and the **future** package. <s>However I get a problem: when I close the app, it doesn't stop (then I have to restart the R session)</s> (see the comment).

```r
library(shiny)
library(waiter)
library(future)
plan(multisession) # important
library(httr)

foo <- function() {
  # Simulte a slow download
  cap_speed <- httr::config(max_recv_speed_large = 10000)
  GET("http://httpbin.org/bytes/102400", cap_speed)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useWaiter(),
  useHostess(),
  waiterShowOnLoad(
    color = "#f7fff7",
    hostess_loader(
      "loader", 
      preset = "circle", 
      text_color = "black",
      class = "label-center",
      center_page = TRUE
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  hostess <- Hostess$new("loader")
  
  f <- future({ foo() })  # Create the future
  
  i <- 0
  while(!resolved(f)) {
    i <- i + 1
    hostess$set(min(99, 10 * i)) # the spinner disappears when 100 is attained
  }
  hostess$close()
  print("done") # do not close the app before
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I see why the app didn't close properly: that's because I closed it before the hostess was finished.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to perform a download in JavaScript with a progress bar.

File ***xhr.js***, to put in the ***www*** subfolder of the app:

```js
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("xhr", function (x) {
  
  // 1. Create a new XMLHttpRequest object
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // 2. Configure it: GET-request for the URL
  let url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stla/bigjson/main/bigjson.json";
  xhr.open("GET", url);

  // 3. Send the request over the network
  xhr.send();

  // 4. This will be called after the response is received
  let response; // variable to store the downloaded file
  xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status != 200) {
      // analyze HTTP status of the response
      alert(`Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`); // e.g. 404: Not Found
    } else {
      // show the result in the console
      console.log(`Done, got ${xhr.response.length} bytes`); // response is the server response
      // store the response 
      // we don't send the response to Shiny here because it would block the progress bar
      response = xhr.response;
    }
  };

  let i = 1000; // this is used to slow down the communication with Shiny
  let totalSize = 100293197; // the size of the downloaded file
  let nsteps = 5; // number of steps for the progress bar
  let threshold = 1 / nsteps;
  xhr.onprogress = function (event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) { // if available, totalSize is not needed
                                  // because it is given in event.total
      let ratio = event.loaded / event.total;
      if (ratio >= threshold) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          Shiny.setInputValue("received", ratio);
          if (ratio === 1) { // send response to Shiny
            Shiny.setInputValue("download", response);
          }
        }, i);
        threshold += 1 / nsteps;
      }
    } else { // event.total is not available
      let ratio = event.loaded / totalSize;
      if (ratio >= threshold) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          Shiny.setInputValue("received", ratio);
          if (ratio === 1) { // send response to Shiny
            Shiny.setInputValue("download", response);
          }
        }, i);
        threshold += 1 / nsteps;
      }
    }
    i += 1000;
  };

  xhr.onerror = function () {
    alert("Request failed");
  };
  
});
```

Here I download a file hosted on Github (***bigjson.json***, approx 100Mb).  The `lengthComputable` of the `onprogress` event is `false`; that means that this event does not provide the total size of the download, and then we have to enter it manually.

This event progressively provides the downloaded size. Since this is fast, I slow down with the help of `setTimeout`.

App:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(src = "xhr.js")),
  br(),
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  br(),
  tags$h2("Response will appear here:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("response")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # progress bar
  progress <- NULL
  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    progress <<- Progress$new(session, min = 0, max = 1)
    progress$set(message = "Download in progress")
    # trigger the download in JavaScript
    session$sendCustomMessage("xhr", TRUE)
  })
  
  # input$received contains the ratio of the download in progress
  observeEvent(input$received, {
    progress$set(value = input$received)
    if(input$received == 1) {
      progress$close()
    }
  })
  
  # input$download contains the downloaded file (here a JSON string)
  output$response <- renderPrint({
    req(input$download)
    substr(input$download, 1, 100)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the respponse. I'm looking for something with waiter package. Have updated my code as I found a API call i can simu;ate from httr package,  It seems to be logically correct, but not sure why the `hostess$set(i * 10)` does not update as expected.